# Result 'NULL' while insert data to MSSQL on PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi all I am trying to insert data to MSSQL on PHP.
However the result came out with 'NULL'. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Database Result:
[Database Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sfet.png)
Attached database image result.

**insert.php**

```
$serverName = "192.168.0.5";
$dbName = "GAProduction";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"GAProduction" );

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO pd_output (location, date_time, qty) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$params = array($_POST["txtlocation"], $_POST["txtdate_time"], $_POST["txtqty"]);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else
{
    echo "Record add successfully";
}

sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

**add.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Production Output</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">Location </div></th>
    <th width="160"> <div align="center">Date </div></th>
    <th width="198"> <div align="center">Quantity </div></th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="txtlocation" size="5"></div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtdate_time" size="20"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtqty" size="20"></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show how the insert page is called (i.e. the complete form with submit or the AJAX call)

Comment: What is your $_POST value at this point?

Comment: @NigelRenI've updated the code, thanks.

Comment: @Armin, I've updated the code, thanks.